# Curl with python is giving error response code 422

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, python-requests

I have issue with running curl statement in python

```sh
import requests,json
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
hostname = "test21"
username = "testuser"
password = "testpassword"
consumer_url = "https://dev21.testing.com:8082/consumers/my_json_test"
consume_json_data = '{"name": "consumer_instance", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}'
json_header = {'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.kafka.json.v1+json'}
def test(consumer_url,consume_json_data,json_header):
    create_consumers_result = requests.post(consumer_url, data=consume_json_data, headers=json_header, auth=(username, password), verify=False)
    print(create_consumers_result)
test(consumer_url,json_data,json_header)
```

is giving response code 422

where as curl -k -u testuser:testpassword POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" --data '{"name": "my_consumer_instance", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}' https://dev21.testing.com:8082/consumers/my_json_test
gives me valid output am i missing anything in python code..?

Comment: If the url requires json input, then you should use `json=consume_json_data`, not `data=consume_json_data`.

Comment: it is giving me response code 500, but curl still works on same command on same server. user@test21: curl -k -u testuser POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" --data '{"name": "my_consumer_instance", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}' https://dev21.testing.com:8082/consumers/my_json_testing
Enter host password for user 'testuser':
output
{"instance_id":"my_consumer_instance","base_uri":"https://dev21.testing.com:8082/consumers/my_json_testing/instances/my_consumer_instance"}

Comment: As John Gordon says `json=consume_json_data`, not `data=consume_json_data` and also `consume_json_data = {"name": "consumer_instance", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}` not `consume_json_data = '{"name": "consumer_instance", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}'` i.e. a dictionary not a string

Comment: Thanks, But i tried updating it as suggested but it still gives me error 422 as response
consume_json_data = {
        "name": "consumer_instance",
        "format": "json",
        "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
}
json=consume_json_data